# How do you remove similar (not duplicated) rows in pandas dataframe using text similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have thousands of data that may or may not be similar to each other. Using python's default function drop_duplicates() doesn't really help since they only detect similar data only, for example, what if my data contains something like these:

1. Hey, good morning!
2. Hey, good morning.

Python wouldn't detect them as duplicates. There are many variations to this really, that simply cleaning the text wouldn't suffice, so I opt for text similarity.

I have tried the following code,

```
import textdistance
from tqdm import tqdm 
tqdm.pandas()

all_sims = []

for id1, text1 in tqdm(enumerate(df1['cleaned'])):
    for id2, text2 in enumerate(df1['cleaned'].iloc[id1:]):
        if id1==id2:
            continue
        sim = textdistance.jaro_winkler(text1, text2)
        if sim>=0.9:
#             print("similarity value: ",sim)
#             print("text 1 >> ",text1)
#             print("text 2 >> ",text2)
#             print("====><====")
            all_sims.append(id1)
```

Basically I tried to iterate all the rows in the column and check it with themselves. If the jaro-winkler value detected turns out to be >= 0.9 then the index will be saved to a list.

I will then remove all these similar indices with the following code.

```
df1[~df1.index.isin(all_sims)]
```

But my code is really slow and inefficient, and I am not sure if it's the right approach. Do you have any idea to improve this?

Comment: Please specify more details like what are the other variations you may expect. It's better if you preprocess the text initially. Must have to change cases as well(convert them all to lower case). Then you can simply use drop_duplicates().

Comment: @LittinRajan I have done the cleansing part too and dropped duplicates after that, now what's left are texts that are similar and only differ in one or two words (text preprocessing won't matter to them and yes I still want to remove these).

Comment: while performing text preprocessing, you can omit the punctuations as well. Just pass the alpha-numeric characters only.

Comment: @LittinRajan already done that. It's really not about the punctuation though. I have also removed stop words, links, hashtags, etc. Like I said it's about one or a few words difference which can't be done through preprocessing only.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import textdistance

# Toy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": [
            "Mulligan Nick",
            "Hitt S C",
            "Breda Joy Mulligen",
            "David James Tsan",
            "Mulligan Nick",
            "Htti S C ",
            "Brenda Joy Mulligan",
            "Dave James Tsan",
        ],
    }
)

# Calculate similarities between rows
# and save corresponding indexes in a new column "match"
df["match"] = df["name"].map(
    lambda x: [
        i
        for i, text in enumerate(df["name"])
        if textdistance.jaro_winkler(x, text) >= 0.9
    ]
)

# Iterate to remove similar rows (keeping only the first one)
indices = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    indices.append(i)
    df = df.drop(
        index=[item for item in row["match"] if item not in indices], errors="ignore"
    )

# Clean up
df = df.drop(columns="match")

print(df)
# Outputs
                 name
0       Mulligan Nick
1            Hitt S C
2  Breda Joy Mulligen
3    David James Tsan
```